# In BrowserSync, how can you match an specific route and redirect?

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

In BrowserSync, how can you match an specific route and redirect?
in other words, if a user enters path of

http://localhost:8080/src/public/App1/Dashboard
I want to redirect to:
http://localhost:8080/src/public/index.html#/App1/Dashboard

this is my current config

```
gulp.task('x_open_server_development_auto', ['x_watch_source'], function () {
    process.stdout.write('Starting browserSync and superstatic...\n');
    browserSync({
        port: 8080,
        open: false,
        files: ['index.html', '**/*.ts'],
        notify: true,
        reloadDebounce: 400,
        server: {
            baseDir: './',
            directory: true
        }
    });
    // exit every 20 minutes so forever will restart it
    setTimeout(function () {
        process.exit()
    }, 3200000);
});
```

tx Sean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`browser-sync` allows you define [middleware](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-middleware) which you can use to handle requests:

```
browserSync({
  port: 8080,
  open: false,
  files: ['index.html', '**/*.ts'],
  notify: true,
  reloadDebounce: 400,
  server: {
    baseDir: './',
      directory: true
  },
  middleware: [
    function(req, res, next) {
      if (/\/src\/public\/App1\/Dashboard\/?/.test(req.url)) {
        res.writeHead(302, {
          'Location': '/src/public/index.html#/App1/Dashboard'
        });
        res.end();
      }
      next();
    }
  ],
});
```